# Extending int array functionality in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, idioms

I'm not exactly sure how to search for this question.

Say I use a bunch of functions on `int array`s, such as subtracting two of them componentwise (if they have the same length) and so forth. Is there an idiomatic way to handle this? How should I lift operations on `int`s (or some other type) to operations on `int array`s (or arrays of some other type)? Should I use a functor or take some other approach?

Edit: I want to be able to lift the arithmetic operations of numeric types like `int`s or `float`s to ones on their corresponding arrays. Should I still just write the functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have these 'Iterators on two lists' for lists.
I suppose they would be enough for what you want to do.

I guess you could use lists instead (or turn your arrays into lists and turning them back again but that sounds unnecessarily costly), or simply coding these functions yourself.

Here is an example:

```
let array_map2 f a a' =
  let n = Array.length a in
  assert (n = Array.length a');
  if n = 0 then [||]
  else begin
    let r = Array.make n (f a.(0) a'.(0)) in
    for i = 0 to n - 1 do
      r.(i) <- f a.(i) a'.(i)
    done ;
    r
  end

array_map2 : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a array -> 'b array -> 'c array
```

This function works (assuming it works) as follows:

```
array_map2 f [| a1 ; a2 ; ... ; an |] [| b1 ; b2 ; ... ; bn |] = [| f a1 b1 ; f a2 b2 ; ... ; f an bn |]
```

Then, thanks to polymorphism you can lift your operations:

```
array_map2 (+) : int array -> int array -> int array
array_map2 (+.) : float array -> float array -> float array
```

Comment: Yeah, I've been relying on writing these functions myself, but I also need to lift the arithmetic operations for types other than `int`, so doing this by hand becomes tedious. Any ideas?

Comment: Polymorphism is the key isn't it? You could use `array_map2 (+) : int array -> int array -> int array` for instance.

Comment: The `array_map2` function given by @Sheeft works for all types, not just ints.

Answer (score 3):

Just write the functions. There is no need to use functors or anything else, just keep it simple and concise. Readability should be the main priority.

If you want your functions to be in the array module, you can use the following trick:

```
module Array = struct 
  include Array
  let diff xs ys = ys
end
```

And now you have a module `Array` with all existing functions, plus yours. Of course, this wouldn't change the real `Array` module and will have effect only in the lexical scope.

## Update

If your algorithm is generic enough to depend only on some specific algebra, then you can abstract this algebra with module type and use functors or first-class modules to parametrize your code with this algebra. A good example, would be a [`sum` function](https://github.com/janestreet/core_kernel/blob/master/src/container.ml#L396) in `Container` interface. It is parametrized with a first class module (a module packed into a value), that must implement [commutative group](https://github.com/janestreet/core_kernel/blob/master/src/commutative_group.ml#L11) algebra (that is required for the sum function). Basically, the usage is something like this:

```
 List.sum (module Int) ~f:ident [1;2;3;4]
```

or

```
 Array.sum (module Int) ~f:ident [| 1;2;3;4|]
```

Also, this code can be later easily rewritten to adopt new [modular implicits](http://www.lpw25.net/ml2014.pdf) that will be available in a next version of OCaml.

Comment: So if I wanted these functions for both `int array`s and `float array`s, say, is it best to define a variant type like `type num = Int of int | Float of float` and then just do case analyses in these functions?